# How to oauth-login a server app via the mobile client (especially iOS, Twitter, but in general too)

Tags: ios, facebook, web-applications, twitter, oauth

We have a web application that supports Facebook and Twitter login/signup via oAuth (and can also post to FB/TW). Now we are building a mobile client and naturally we want people to be able to login-signup via FB-Twitter on mobile as well, on iOS even using system-integrated accounts.

Now mobile app and our server app are two different apps, however, and if I get oAuth correctly, we'll need to have two authentications: one for a mobile client (system account can be used), another one for a server (we'll have to show WebView for it).

Yet some existing apps seem to be fine with single authentication only (e.g. Flickr and Foursquare! At least 4sq seems to be fine with iOS system FB account only. How is it possible?

- Do they share consumer key/secret between mobile and web app making it essentially the same app?
- Do they use some FB-specific extension to oAuth
- Do they only use auth token wherever it comes from making it a user ID?
- Something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this may help someone who finds their way here.

[Twitter Reverse Auth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth)